# Gazebo Q&A is down

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like Gazebo Forum is down. So, who do I have to ask?

http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/answers.gazebosim.org/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219969/gazebo-q&a-is-down/) by [Daiki Maekawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19960/daiki-maekawa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2015-10-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-10-27**:
Hopefully it didn't get hacked again... You could ask Nate Koenig from OSRF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ticketed on OSRF bitbucket. https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1775/answers-web-site-is-down Hope it'll soon be backed up without harm!

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daiki Maekawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19960/daiki-maekawa/) on 2015-10-27**:
@130s Thx! I checked that there are no problems with the site right now.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.ros.org/users/4654/chapulina/) on 2015-11-01**:
The site has been upgraded and is back up.